# How to load a HTML file within a div in React App

Tags: html, reactjs, cheerio

We have a requirement to load an HTML file within a react component. We can load the HTML file within a div using the "**Cheerios**" package. But the issue is, that we have a few hyperlinks within an HTML file and the respective files are also there. Now the requirement is when we click on the hyperlink, we want the HTML file to be loaded with the same div. Please find the folder structure below.

*public/

- index.html
- sample.html
- sample1.html*

**index.html:**

```
<HTML>
<header></header>
<body>
<ul>
 <li><a href="sample.html"> Sample</a></li>
<li><a href="sample1.html"> Sample1</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I can load the index.html with the react component. But when I Click on the sample.html link from index.html, the sample.html file path is updated in the browser bar.

Comment: Of course this updates the window location, that's what `<a>` does. Have you tried an `<iframe>` with a source dynamically set by React? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: Team is not preferring to have a <iframe>. So looking for some solution without that.

Comment: Cheerio is a port of jQuery to the backend Node where there's no native HTML parser. Now you're bringing it back to the front end, even though React and normal JS/jQuery already have native HTML parsers--why? What sort of application are you trying to build here? The requirements are [unusual](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676)--almost never is there a reason to use Cheerio on the front end, much less in React.